# Cannot program Arduino Micro in OSX without hard resetting the board every time

Tags: arduino-ide, avrdude, arduino-micro

I am experiencing a problem when programming Arduino Micro in OSX Mavericks. I have tried to reproduce this problem in XCode and Arduino IDE and it is persistent. I need to make a hard-reset at the same time as a click the "program" button.

I have tried to use the new Leonardo bootloader to see if it solves my issue, but its still persistent.

I am running avrdude 6.1, what is the problem?

Stacktrace:

```
---- Size ----

Binary sketch size:   24162 bytes (of a 28672 byte maximum)
Estimated SRAM used:  733 bytes (of a 2560 byte maximum)
Elapsed time: 5.2 s

---- Reset ---- 

screen -X kill

No screen session found.

make: [reset] Error 1 (ignored)

sleep 1

9.2-RESET:  <   micro   ./ ./   

stty -f /dev/tty.usbmodem1411 1200

---- Upload ---- 

10.6-UPLOAD:  <     micro   ./  


/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -patmega32u4 -C/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -D -cavr109 -b57600 -P/dev/tty.usbmodem1411 -Uflash:w:Builds/embeddedcomputing.hex:i


Connecting to programmer: .avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

Comment: Try updating the bootloader. Also, is the problem also present on none-OSX systems?

Comment: @Gerben, i have tried updating it, still the same result. I am considering trying Leonardo bootloader instead to see if it does any good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [Arduino.cc article](http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoLeonardoMicro) describes the differences between Leonard & Micro vs. other Arduinos, including the fact that Micro does not have a separate USB processor on board but creates a virtual USB with the main processor. There is no (or a very different) auto-reset mechanism. There is apparently a way for the IDE to open the Mac's USB at 1200 baud to cause the Micro to reset; then the IDE can wait for the virtual USB to re-appear. But it also says you may need to use the reset button suggesting the 1200 baud dance doesn't work all that reliably.

Comment: Thats how far i have reached so far, but unfortunately it does not solve my problem as resetting manually every time i am uploading a sketch is a pain in the @$$.

Comment: I believe the reliability of the reset depends on the sketch (i.e. that it's possible to write code that inadvertently disables the auto reset code). Have you tried reproducing this with e.g. a blink sketch?